# "There is" in Latin

Tags: idiom, example-request, spanish

In English you use the phrasal verb **there+[to be]** to mean something different than just an object being placed somewhere visible or known to the speaker and/or listener (i.e., *there*).

- According to [the Cambridge University Dictionary,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/there-is-there-s-and-there-are) *we use* there is *and* there are *when we first refer to the existence or presence of someone or something*.
- [This dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/there-is-are) defines *there+to be* as *used to say that something exists or happens*

The same happens with Italian *c'è* and its corresponding plural and other tenses. In Spanish there is even a special *"impersonal"* conjugation of the verb *haber* —*hay*— for that meaning (even when in English one would use the plural form *there are*). *Hay* has very little use apart from this meaning, and no other verbs have such impersonal form, that I'm aware.

---

My gut feeling is that in Latin one should preferably use **est**, while **exsistit** and even **ecce + esse** (possibly elided) could be of some use in certain contexts.

**My question is: Could you provide any examples, either Classical or from the Vulgate, that convey something like this meaning of *there is* in a natural way?** I'm interested in both affirmative and interrogative sentences, and if there is any rule of thumb as for what (if anything) makes something different than *est* (ecce, exsistit) preferable. Any additional grammatical insights and/or partial answers are also welcome.

Comment: Side comment: believe it or not, the other day I had a dream where I had no other language than Latin to communicate with someone specific. In my dream I used _exsisto_, knowing that it wasn't quite natural. _Esse_ came to my mind only a few hours after waking up.

Comment: Dreaming in Latin. That is on another level!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The next time you get into that dream, use a plain *est*.
Here is an example from Caesar:

> ***Flumen est*** Arar, quod per fines Haeduorum et Sequanorum in Rhodanum influit…
>   (*Commentarii de bello Gallico* I.12)
>
> **There is a river** called the Saone, which flows through the territories of the Aedui and Sequani into the Rhone…
>   (W. A. McDevitte and W. S. Bohn, 1869)

For introducing simple things like this, the most idiomatic way I know is to use *est*.
Using *ecce* gives emphasis, which is often unwanted.
The point is to say "there is a river", not "lo and behold, a river".

For questions, you can use *estne* for "is there".
Here is an example:

> *Estne adhuc aliquid mali in orbe mecum?*
>   (Lucius Annaeus Seneca iunior, *Hercules Oetaeus* 1399–1400)
>
> Is there still anything bad in the world with me?
>   (my quick translation)

There are also examples of *estne* with a dative of possession, but I guess those would not usually correspond to an English question with "is there".

Comment: "Arar is a river, which..." is just as well possible methinks.

Comment: Just to add, [Latin for beginners](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/18251/18251-h/simple.html)  mentions explicitly at least twice (in [#86 footnote 1](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/18251/18251-h/simple.html#sec86),  and [#96 foot note 4](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/18251/18251-h/simple.html#sec96)) that in order to use *esse* in the sense of *there is*, it should come before the subject, and even as the first word in the sentence. "Est in vîcô vir bonus" = There is a good  man in the town

Answer (score 4):

In the first sentence of St. Augustine's Confessions:

"...et sapientiae tuae non est numerus."

The English translation by John K. Ryan renders this as:

"and to your wisdom *there is* no limit."

**EDIT:**

After doing some research, including reading the discussion linked in the comments below, I don't prefer Ryan's translation of "sapientiae tuae" as dative. Augustine is echoing the psalms, whose corresponding parts seem to be **genitive** and are translated as such in the **Douay-Rheims**, which also employs **"there is no"** for **"non est"**, to tie these two discussions together at least superficially:

http://vulgate.org/ot/psalms_144.htm verse 3

http://vulgate.org/ot/psalms_146.htm verse 5

I prefer a translation like "of your wisdom, there is no measure."

Comment: I would take this as a dative of possession, actually, even though "there is" works for it in English. (In other words, I'd translate it as "your wisdom has no limit".)

Comment: Didn't we discuss this very passage on here recently?

Comment: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13006/grammar-of-sapientiae-tuae-non-est-numerus/13012#13012